# Satellizer Facebook Login 'Wrong Number of Segments error' LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-5, facebook-login, jwt, satellizer

I have been playing with JWT Tokens lately, using Firebase\JWT and Satelizer.

I have been trying to integrate with laravel-angular project I have been working on.

Here is the sample code from Satelizers.io for facebook login: (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/php/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php)

```
/**
     * Login with Facebook.
     */
    public function facebook(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $params = [
            'code' => $request->input('code'),
            'client_id' => $request->input('clientId'),
            'redirect_uri' => $request->input('redirectUri'),
            'client_secret' => Config::get('app.facebook_secret')
        ];
        // Step 1. Exchange authorization code for access token.
        $accessTokenResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token', [
            'query' => $params
        ]);
        $accessToken = json_decode($accessTokenResponse->getBody(), true);
        // Step 2. Retrieve profile information about the current user.
        $fields = 'id,email,first_name,last_name,link,name';
        $profileResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me', [
            'query' => [
                'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token'],
                'fields' => $fields
            ]
        ]);
        $profile = json_decode($profileResponse->getBody(), true);
        // Step 3a. If user is already signed in then link accounts.
        if ($request->header('Authorization'))
        {
            $user = User::where('facebook', '=', $profile['id']);
            if ($user->first())
            {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'There is already a Facebook account that belongs to you'], 409);
            }
            $token = explode(' ', $request->header('Authorization'))[1];
            $payload = (array) JWT::decode($token, Config::get('app.token_secret'), array('HS256')); // STUCK HERE
            $user = User::find($payload['sub']);
            $user->facebook = $profile['id'];
            $user->email = $user->email ?: $profile['email'];
            $user->displayName = $user->displayName ?: $profile['name'];
            $user->save();
            return response()->json(['token' => $this->createToken($user)]);
        }
        // Step 3b. Create a new user account or return an existing one.
        else
        {
            $user = User::where('facebook', '=', $profile['id']);
            if ($user->first())
            {
                return response()->json(['token' => $this->createToken($user->first())]);
            }
            $user = new User;
            $user->facebook = $profile['id'];
            $user->email = $profile['email'];
            $user->displayName = $profile['name'];
            $user->save();
            return response()->json(['token' => $this->createToken($user)]);
        }
    }
```

I am able to get the Facebook profile inforamtion, but I keep getting stuck on this line:

```
$payload = (array) JWT::decode($token, Config::get('app.token_secret'), array('HS256')); // STUCK HERE
```

It is throwing a 'Wrong number of segments' error when trying to read the taken set by satelizer.

I have inspected the token and it does not follow the typical JWT format. (there are no 'dots' in the token)

Has anyone expereinced this before? How do I go about solving this issue?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: have you specified the token here ? https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/php/config/app.php

Comment: Not sure, I remember seeing that and being curious as to what the 'secret' is.  Is it given to you when you set up your developer account with the company.  Google for example